# How would I write a changed variable to my config.js file for a permanent change?

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js, replit

**My Problem**

I am currently writing a Discord bot to be used on one server at the moment. I have set up a command that will change the prefix of the bot's commands but as soon as I restart my repl, it resets to the original prefix. I would like to change the command so that it will write to my `config.js` file to stop this from happening.

---

**What I've Tried So Far**

To be honest, I haven't tried anything yet as I have no idea where to start

---

**My code Files**

config.js file:

```
var config={};
config.token = "My Bot Token";
config.prefix = "//";
config.statusMessage = "video games | (" + config.prefix + "help)";
config.dbltoken = undefined;
module.exports = config;
```

change-prefix.js file:

```
config = require('../config.js');
module.exports = (client, message, args) => {
  config.prefix = args;
  message.reply("Prefix has been changed to: " + config.prefix);
  console.log("Command Used: Change-Prefix");
}
```

---

**What Should Happen**

The `change-prefix.js` file should successfully write the new prefix determined by the user to the `config.js` file. At this moment in time, I have no errors, but I would like to change this as it would vastly improve the user experience for my bot.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to write the file, you can use `fs` module. The code below saves custom prefix to `prefix.txt` file and checks if it exists every time you start your repl. If not, it's using the default value.

> **Note**: the code doesn't have any error handling or any other features, it's just a simple code to show you the idea. In real life scenario, you'll probably want to save your prefix to database, add per-server prefix setting, filter messages from other bots, include prefix in command invocation. Just one more thing - **please put Discord token in `.env`, not in config file.**

```js
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const fs = require('fs');
const config = require('./config.js');
const client = new Discord.Client();

// If prefix.txt exist, use it. Otherwise, get data from config file
let prefix = fs.existsSync('prefix.txt') ? fs.readFileSync('prefix.txt').toString() : config.prefix;

client.on('message', (msg) => {
  // 'set prefix XXX' to change your prefix to XXX
  if (/^set prefix /i.exec(msg.content)) {
    const newPrefix = msg.content.split(' ')[2];
    fs.writeFile("./prefix.txt", newPrefix, function(err) {
    if(err) {
        return console.log(err);
    }
    prefix = newPrefix;
    console.log(`Prefix changed to ${prefix}`);
}); 
  }
  // 'show prefix' to show current prefix
  if (/^show prefix/i.exec(msg.content)) {
    console.log(`Prefix is ${prefix}`);
  }; 
  });

client.on('ready', () => {
  console.log(`I'm in`);
});

client.login(process.env.DISCORD_TOKEN);
```